# SharePoint Delegate Controls (GlobalSiteLink3)

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

If I add a SharePoint delegate control to my master page with a ControlID of GlobalSiteLink3, it then renders certain social image buttons. Where are these defined? How does this delegate control 'lookup' the social network menu for rendering? I thought the available controls to a delegate control were found in an xml file but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but these must be defined in a assembly somewhere or in the ressources. One thing thought, if you want to customize that I would just remove this and make my own system. If you want to customize only the image, override the css and input your own image.